# How can I do a boost style function object in Java?

Tags: java, boost

I'm a fan of the composition pattern in C++, and I'm trying to design code similarly in Java.

I have the following class set up for doing callbacks in C++ using boost function objects:

```
class MyEventMarshaller
{
public:
    void subscribeMessage(std::string eventKey, boost::function<void (DataType1, DataType2)> callBack)
    {
         m_callbackMap[eventKey].push_back(callBack);
    }
    void marshallLoop()
    {
         while(m_doStuff)
         {
             //Something interesting happens
             std::string eventKey = getInterestingEventKey();
             if(m_callbackMap.find(eventKey) != m_callbackMap.end())
             {
                  BOOST_FOREACH(boost::function<void (DataType1, DataType2)> cb, m_callbackMap[eventKey])
                  {
                       cb(getDataOne(), getDataTwo());
                  }
             }
         }
    }
protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<boost::function<void (DataType1, DataType2)> > m_callbackMap;
};
```

In this situation, a class wanting an event registers its handler member function:

```
m_eventHandlerPtr->subscribeMessage("SOME_EVENT_KEY",
                                    boost::bind(&MyClass::MyHandler, this, _1, _2));
```

As you can see, any class can register for a myriad of messages that all share the same signature, and the event marshaller class doesn't need to be aware of what types of classes might be registering for any messages. One could take the design a step further and hide the marshaller's subscribeMessage() method in a function object, making it so registering classes don't have to be aware of the marshaller class type either.

My question is this:

***How would I best duplicate boost function objects in Java for the purpose of callback handling? Is it even possible?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 has lambdas: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

So you can define any single-method interface:

```
public interface BinaryFunction {
    String invoke(Object dataOne, Object dataTwo);
}
```

And implement your event marshaller as in C++:

```
class MyEventMarshaller
{
    private boolean doStuff = true;
    private Map<String, List<BinaryFunction> > callbackMap = new HashMap<String, List<BinaryFunction>>();

    public void subscribeMessage(String eventKey, BinaryFunction callBack)
    {
        if (!callbackMap.containsKey(eventKey)) {
            callbackMap.put(eventKey, new ArrayList<BinaryFunction>());
        }

        callbackMap.get(eventKey).add(callBack);
    }

    public void marshallLoop()
    {
        while(doStuff)
        {
            //Something interesting happens
            String eventKey = getInterestingEventKey();

            if (callbackMap.containsKey(eventKey))
            {
                for (BinaryFunction cb : callbackMap.get(eventKey))
                {
                    System.out.println("Debug: " + cb.invoke(getDataOne(), getDataTwo()));
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    private Object getDataTwo() { return null; } // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    private Object getDataOne() { return null; } // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String getInterestingEventKey() { return "yep"; }

}
```

Now, a demo program would look like:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyEventMarshaller instance = new MyEventMarshaller();

        instance.subscribeMessage("yep", (a,b) -> MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", a, b));

        instance.marshallLoop();
    }
}
```

The lambda expression `(a,b) -> MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", a, b)` implicitly implements the `BinaryFunction` interface, and is equivalent to doing:

```
    instance.subscribeMessage("yep", new BinaryFunction() {
        @Override
        public String invoke(Object a, Object b) {
            return MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", a, b);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Will this work for non-static member functions, i.e. could I do:

SomeClassType someClassInstance = new SomeClassType();

instance.subscribeMessage("KEY", (a,b) -> someClassInstance.handleSomeKey(a,b));

Comment: As long as the captures are final, yeah no problem. [That linked page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) describes perfectly what things are "par for the course" in lambdas. But you can already reason about this using the same guidelines as captures from anonymous nested types from Java 7 and Java 6 (5, too IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

In java you can't pass a function as a variable but it is possible to pass a callback interface with a particular method (doSomething) to be called exactly as you call the function in C++.

```
public interface Callback {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class MyCallback implements Callback {
    public void doSomething() {
         // Do something
    }
}

...

private List<Callback> callbacks;

...

public void addCallback(Callback callback) {
    callbacks.add(callback);
}

public void do() {
    for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
        callback.doSomething();
    }
}
```